# How to implement IntoIterator on a StackVec

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I am trying to write a `Vec` like object with a fixed size to be used on the stack.

This is part of an online course I am trying to complete [Assignment 1, Phase 2A](https://cs140e.sergio.bz/assignments/1-shell/).

I am having problems implementing the `IntoIterator` trait.

The code for the `StructVec`

```rust
#![no_std]

pub struct StackVec<'a, T: 'a> {
    storage: &'a mut [T],
    len: usize
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> StackVec<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(storage: &'a mut [T]) -> StackVec<'a, T> {
        StackVec { storage, len: 0 }
    }

    pub fn with_len(storage: &'a mut [T], len: usize) -> StackVec<'a, T> {
        StackVec { storage, len }
    }

    pub fn capacity(&self) -> usize {
        self.storage.len()
    }

    pub fn truncate(&mut self, len: usize) {
        if len < self.len {
            self.len = len;
        }
    }

    pub fn into_slice(self) -> &'a mut [T] {
        &mut self.storage[..self.len]
    }

    pub fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] {
        &self.storage[..self.len]
    }

    pub fn as_mut_slice(&mut self) -> &mut [T] {
        &mut self.storage[..self.len]
    }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.len == 0
    }

    pub fn is_full(&self) -> bool {
        self.len == self.storage.len()
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) -> Result<(), ()> {
        if self.is_full() {
            return Err(());
        }
        self.storage[self.len] = value;
        self.len += 1;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

I was able to get implement the `IntoIterator` trait by returning the iterator of the underlying array:

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    type IntoIter = core::slice::IterMut<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.storage.into_iter()
    }
}
```

However that's not really what I want as it will iterate through the entire array instead of just the items that were pushed onto it.

I've tried returning an iterator from an array slice of the underlying array but I get caught out by lifetimes:

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = core::slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.as_slice().into_iter()
    }
}
```

Fails to compile with the error

```
error[E0597]: `self` does not live long enough
   --> src/lib.rs:165:9
    |
165 |         self.as_slice().into_iter()
    |         ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
166 |     }
    |     - borrowed value only lives until here
    |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 160:1...
   --> src/lib.rs:160:1
    |
160 | / impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
161 | |     type Item = &'a T;
162 | |     type IntoIter = core::slice::Iter<'a, T>;
163 | |
...   |
166 | |     }
167 | | }
    | |_^
```

I've also tried creating a new `Iterator` entirely but I get caught out again!

```rust
struct Iter<'a, T: 'a> {
    stack_vec: StackVec<'a, T>,
    start: usize,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let start = self.start;
        if start < self.stack_vec.len {
            self.start += 1;
            Some(self.stack_vec[start])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = self.stack_vec.len - self.start;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}
```

Fails to compile with the error:

```
error[E0508]: cannot move out of type `[T]`, a non-copy slice
   --> src/lib.rs:148:18
    |
148 |             Some(self.stack_vec[start])
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of here
```

I've tried looking at crates that do the same thing but either they use the `std` library which I can't use for this assignment, or I don't understand how to port their code to mine.

https://github.com/bluss/arrayvec

https://github.com/danielhenrymantilla/stackvec-rs/blob/master/src/stackvec/traits/into_iter.rs

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Silly question. Does it have to be `IntoIterator` for `StackVec<'a, T>`? Can it not be `IntoIterator` for `&'_ StackVec<'a, T>`, which solves all your lifetime problems since you will still own the `StackVec` while iterating?

Comment: The assignment and to implement the iterator for both `StackVec` and `&StackVec` so yes I was able to do it for `&StackVec` just by returning an iterator of the slice but I need both.

Comment: Okay :-) Chris Pearce sorted your issue out for the owned `IntoIterator` so it's all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fairly simple extension of your original idea, you can limit the number of elements that an iterator can return using the `take` method. That turns your `IntoIterator` implementation into:

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    type IntoIter = std::iter::Take<core::slice::IterMut<'a, T>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.storage.into_iter().take(self.len)
    }
}
```

You ran into issues with your other attempt to implement `IntoIterator` because the `into_iter` method takes ownership of `self`. This means that once the function exits, you need to make sure you've moved or copied all of the you want to use in your iterator out of `self`. Since `as_slice` only borrows, you can't return an iterator to the slice from your function (the data it's borrowing from will be dropped).

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = core::slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        //       ^ no & or &mut here means this function takes ownership of self
        self.as_slice().into_iter()
    }
}
```

You can still create a non-owning iterator of your `StackVec` struct, but you wouldn't do it with `IntoIterator`. Instead, simply create a method on your struct called `iter`:

```rust
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&T> {
    self.storage.iter().take(self.len)
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't think to look at the iterator methods. Thank you. I would still be interested to know if there is a solution that uses the slice, but your answer is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Updated the answer to offer a solution for the unowned slice version.